# How do I temporarily disable AppStats in my Google App Engine application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I recently configured my app to use the new AppStats feature of GAE. However, while debugging it, the extremely verbose logging from AppStats is annoying & I'd like to disable it while I'm debugging and then turn it back on later. Surely there is a single line I can add to or modify in a config file that will let me do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [configuring appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html#Configuring_Appstats) docs: configuration is performed by creating your own `appengine_config.py` in your app's root directory.  Best documentation of what you can do in that config file is the sample one supplied with your SDK, which you can also look at [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/appstats/sample_appengine_config.py).  To disable stats, if you're using Django, just comment out the line

```
google.appengine.ext.appstats.recording.AppStatsDjangoMiddleware
```

in your Diango `settings.py` file; if you're **not** using Django, in the function that should be in your `appengine_config.py` file and read

```
def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
  from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording
  app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
  return app
```

just comment out the first two lines of the body, so it reads instead

```
def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
  # from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording
  # app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
  return app
```

If you insist on it being a single-line change, you can avoid commenting the `from` statement -- per se, it's innocuous, though it may microscopically slow you down (which is why I'd comment it out even though innocuous;-).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but how about this:

Add a config.py where you define the DEBUG flag (or if you have it defined elsewhere, even better). And then:

```
from config import DEBUG

def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
    if not DEBUG:       
        from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording
        app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
    return app
```

EDIT: Advantage of this method is you can use the same debug flag elsewhere in your app.